# How to access a build's custom variable in script in TFS 2015?

Tags: variables, powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

In Team Foundation Server 2015 in build definition I use my custom variables defined on Variables tab. Is there any way to access them in PowerShell build step like predefined variables can be accessed e.g. "$env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME"? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[disclaimer: I work on the new build system]

I often advise folks to use the cmdline task or a cmd script to print out the variables (call set on windows, env on *nix).  There's docs etc... but actually running it will show exactly what is really available.

Add cmdline task (in utility) with tool = cmd and arguments = /k set

Variables on the definitions variable tab should be available as environment variables upper cased

So:

```
my variable
```

Is available as the environment variable

```
MY VARIABLE
```

There is a current bug, it should be per spec MY_VARIABLE.  On the xplat agent/shell script it's MY_VARIABLE

This makes it accessible to cmd, powershell, shell etc... scripts.

Comment: Thank you bryanmac, I should realize this. It's very useful method for many circumstances. The environment variable I've searched for is BUILD_DROPLOCATION, so it seems "BUILD_" prefix is used for custom build variables.

Comment: Nope - there's system and build variables that start with system.xxx and build.xxx - those are converted to envvar toUpper and space -> _.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables

Comment: vars on the def vars tab should just be capped and underscored (althought bug I mentioned above)

Comment: Note: There seems to be something special/magical (and undocumented) about a variable named “DropLocation”.  It gets turned into the BUILD_DROPLOCATION environment variable, and you can’t use it as $(DropLocation) in the UI.  You have to use it as $(Build.DropLocation).  However, most custom variables don’t get the “Build.” prefix stuck on them (e.g., a ProductName variable can be used as $(ProductName) in the UI and as the PRODUCTNAME environment variable).  I'm on 2015 Update 2, but I suspect @Michal ran into this special case even in RTM.