# Send command output as log in tfs build email

Tags: node.js, xslt, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have a build that running some npm tests with TFS 2017.
I set an email notification for failed builds.

Developers asks to get more information about the npm test instead of just "npm failed with exit code 1" so I want to get the entire output as a log file attached to the email or parse the output and send it as the error message to the email notification.

I tried to modify the BuildCompletedEvent.xsl to get different value but I keep getting the uninformative npm failure message.

Does someone know of a way to send the entire command output to the email or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the build log contain all of the npm tests output. You could use rest api or powershell script to catch the related build log. Detail steps please refer this question: [Get zipped TFS 2015 (vNext) build output logs through powershell (just like the download link after the build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715860/get-zipped-tfs-2015-vnext-build-output-logs-through-powershell-just-like-the)

Then just use some custom tasks to send mails with attachment in the build definition such as [send email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) or [email](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Email) task.  Or you could write the task to meet your own requirement, for how to please take a look at this blog: [Sending Email Notification from VSTS/TFS Build](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/12/19/sending-email-notification-from-vststfs-build/)